# SUBMENU dropdowns de bootstrap 4 no sale a la derecha

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

buenas tardes y de antemano muchas gracias, tengo este codigo en el que intento hacer que un dropdowns me salga a la derecha pero no hay manera si lo pruebo con el menu principal si sale no se si hay conflito con un submenu.

la idea es que el submenu al desplegarse salga al frente osea con la opcion dropright de bootstrap pero como comento no hay forma siempre me sale hacia abajo.

si alguien me puede ayudar le agradeceria mucho

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="principal.php">Vicky Hepldesk</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="myMenu">
                <li class="dropdown nav-item active mx-3">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"
                        v-pre>
                        Administrador<span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#3E3E3E ;">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Usuarios</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="roles.php"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Roles</a></li>
                                <!-- aca en esta parte no sale el menu a la derecha -->
                                <li class="dropdown dropright nav-item active mx-3">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                        <i class="fas fa-laptop">&nbsp;</i>Equipos<span class="caret"></a>   
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#3E3E3E;">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Perfil</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cuenta</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Soporte</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Impresoras</a></li>                            
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item">&nbsp;</i>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active mx-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active mx-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">link</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mx-5" id="myMenu">
                    <li class="dropdown nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"
                            v-pre>
                            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){echo $_SESSION['login'];}?><span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="background-color:#3E3E3E;">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cuenta</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Soporte</a></li>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../funciones/cerrarsesion.php">&nbsp;</i>Cerrar Sesión</a> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```